# Typescript equivalent of C# ToLookup

Tags: typescript

I have a class that contains a `specCode` property, which is not a unique key. When I have an array of those objects, I want to convert it to a dictionary where the key is the `specCode`, and then the value is all the array items that have that `specCode`.

Right now I'm doing it manually like so:

```js
const skusBySpecCode: { [key: string]: Sku[] } = {}

for (const sku of x.skus) {
    if (!skusBySpecCode.hasOwnProperty(sku.specCode))
        skusBySpecCode[sku.specCode] = []
    
    skusBySpecCode[sku.specCode].push(sku)
}
```

Is there an easier way to do that?  In C# I'd do something like this:

```cs
theArray
    .ToLookup(x => x.SpecCode)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use `reduce` here to *reduce* your array into an object. Reduce takes a generic parameter, which is the type of the accumulator. Here it should be `{ [key: string]: Sku[] }`, but you could also use `Record<string, Sku[]>`.

```
const skusBySpecCode = skus.reduce<{ [key: string]: Sku[] }>((table, sku) => ({
    ...table,
    [sku.specCode]: [...(table[sku.specCode] ?? []), sku],
}), {});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weQxXw)

Comment: Wow that's ugly :)